# В Firefox 77.0.1 изменение масштаба страницы не действует на списки <select>

Tags: html, firefox

Пример кода:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Some text</h1>
<select>
    <option>First item</option>
    <option>Second item</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Шаги для воспроизведения:

1. Создать файл с указанным выше HTML-кодом;
2. Открыть файл в Firefox 77.0.1;
3. Открыть  мышкой
4. Зажать "Ctrl" и покрутить колёсиком мышки так, чтобы масштаб страницы стал 200%. Тогда надписаь "Some text" увеличится вдвое;
5. Снова открыть  мышкой. Пункты списка останутся такие же по размеру, как и были в "3)".

Почему Firefox 77.0.1 так работает? Это баг или фича? Может быть, есть какие-то параметры, которые можно прописать, например, в тэге , чтобы это исправить?

P.S. В Firefox 69.0.1 списки масштабируются корректно. В нескольких разных версиях Chrome - тоже.

Comment: Вам туда https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

В Firefox 78.0.1 проблему исправили. Вопрос закрыт.